# Android Instant Apps Play Store

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Lots of info about these apps needing to be deployed via the play store.

But cannot find official docs regarding if we could deploy these apps using a private custom app store....

Is there some kind of dependency between instant apps and the google play store?

Anyone have a pointer?

Best writeup I have found so far with references. [What Android Instant Apps could mean for publishers](http://www.pagelizard.com/android-instant-apps-publishers/)

But on the google page, no details about deploying through custom play store or any alternatives..

Comment: Why would Google have documentation about a different Play Store?

Comment: While I agree with this statement, at least they could document if it were possible to use instant apps from alternative app stores?

Is there some play store specific dependency for instant apps?

Comment: It's still in Early Access Preview state.

Comment: Considering how the tech prolly works and how it is back compatible to Gingerbread, I would bet you it will work with Google Play Services, that means, it also needs the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

They announced this feature in Google I/O this year. They haven't released this to all developers but have a signup form for early access. You can find out more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html).

At the very least, it will probably use Google Play Services, I think. Confirmation on it being Play Store only will probably come in the future once they open up SDK access to the public.